# How to solve factorial even numbers on the n number, then multiply them

Tags: python, function, recursion, functional-programming, multiplication

For example there are 3 then the program will
multiplying the first 3 factorials  2 x 4 x 6 = 48. For example if the user wants 3 then the program will multiply the first 3 factorials only and the sum value will decrease if the initial value is even. type int which contains a lot of even numbers that are wanted and will continue to grow in each recursive

**Call:**

```
Print (Value (number, initial))
print(value(3,0))
```

**Output:**

```
48
```

**Explanation:**

The first 3 even values are 2,4,6. So the results of their multiplication will be yield 48.

Sorry but what is wrong with my program:

```
def value(number,initial):

    while(initial<=(number)):

        print((initial*2), end="")

        initial = (initial+1)

        print("%d *" %(initial),end='')

        return initial * (str(value(number,initial)))


value(3,0)
```

Comment: Could you declare what does the second parameter do in your code?

Comment: It aims to fill in the amount is 3 and the beginning is 0 (always 0 when the program starts)

Comment: It starts with 0 but exclude 0,right?Because `0 x any = 0`.

Comment: Yah right, and how to multiply it, because it starts from 0 and multiplied by 0 then all results are 0

Comment: Hai can I ask you, why we need use a lambda?

Comment: `lambda` represents the operation of two elements in the list.

Comment: I think i understand now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `reduce`?

You could generate a `range` which full with the number starts with `initial` and the amount is the `number`

```
from functools import reduce

def value(number, initial):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(initial + 2, (initial + 2) + 2 * number, 2))

print(value(3, 0))
# 48
```